# Why does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{n^x + x^2}{n^x +x} = 1$ for a constant $n \gt 1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Why does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{n^x + x^2}{n^x +x} = 1$ for a constant $n \gt 1$ but infinity when constant $n \leq 1$ ?

I understand intuitively that when $n$ is less than or equal to $1$, $n^x$ has to approach $0$ and so eventually $x^2$ and $x$ become larger than $n^x$ so $x^2$ being larger than $x$ causes the limit to approach infinity and likewise when $n$ is greater than $1$, $n^x$ eventually becomes larger than $x^2$ and $x$ so these terms cause the limit to approach $1$, but how can I prove this formally?

Comment: I fixed it. They should have been switched. Thank you. I hope that mistake didn't deter people from answering

Comment: Many ways to prove this depending on your preference. One simple way (imo) is to use L'Hopital on the $\infty/\infty$ limits $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{n^x}$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{n^x}$ to prove that they both are $0$ when $n>1$ and then write $\frac{n^x+x^2}{n^x+x} = \frac{1+\frac{x^2}{n^x}}{1 + \frac{x}{n^x}}$ and take the limit. Note that $n^x = e^{\log(n) x}$ which makes it simple to compute the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Put $n^x$ in factor :

$$\frac{n^x + x^2}{n^x+x} = \frac{ 1 + \frac{x^2}{n^x}}{ 1 + \frac{x}{n^x} }$$

And remark that $\lim_{x\to  +\infty} \frac{x}{n^x} = 0$ (same thing with $x^2$)

Indeed, $n^x = e^{x\ln(n)}$, so $\frac{x}{n^x} = xe^{-x\ln(n)} $

Comment: a side note is $x\cdot e^{-x\ln n} \to 0$ by L'hospital's rule

Comment: That side note was what I needed I think. So I can use that to show that $n^x$ goes to $0$ if $n$ is less than or equal to $1$ right?